# Cannot submit form after preventDefault Jquery ajax wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am submitting a form with ajax and saving the values to the db on submit. here is the form code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                        $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var form = $(this);
                            var data = $('#form').serialize();
                            var goToPaypal = false;

                            if(goToPaypal == false){
                                e.preventDefault()
                            }else{
                                form.submit();
                            }

                            $.post( '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', {action:'enroll_data', data: data}, function(success){

                                alert(success);
                                if(success == 'success'){
                                    goToPaypal = true;
                                }else{
                                    alert('Failed to process form data');
                                }


                            });
                        });
                    });
```

the form action is as follows

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
```

But the form is not submitting and redirecting to pay pall after successfully saving values to the database. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the form submit after the ajax was successful

```
if(success == 'success'){
  form.submit();
}else{
   alert('Failed to process form data');
}
```

or change the event to a click event

```
$('#form').find('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
                            var form = $('#form');
                            var data = $('#form').serialize();
                            var goToPaypal = false;

                            if(goToPaypal == false){
                                e.preventDefault()
                            }else{
                                form.submit();
                            }

                            $.post( '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', {action:'enroll_data', data: data}, function(success){

                                alert(success);
                                if(success == 'success'){
                                    goToPaypal = true;
                                    form.submit();
                                }else{
                                    alert('Failed to process form data');
                                }


                            });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I have done that already but still form does not go to paypal URL

Comment: is your ajax successful ?

Comment: did you try the click event?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution removing **preventDefault()** form the top does the trick. The form is now saving the values in the database as well as redirecting to paypal. I added preventDefault() in the fail massage of ajax request so that form will not submit if there is and error in query. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is regarding code structure. Don't use preventDefault again and again.

> Structure your code as following.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                        $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
                           // e.preventDefault(); remove this extra code                            
                            var form = $(this);
                            var data = $('#form').serialize();
                            var goToPaypal = false;
                            if(goToPaypal == false){
                                e.preventDefault(); //semi-colon missing, use prevent default here to stop execution on error
                            }else{
                                form.submit();
                            }
$.post( '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', {action:'enroll_data', data: data}, function(success){
alert(success);
                                if(success == 'success'){
                                    goToPaypal = true;
                                }else{
                                    alert('Failed to process form data');
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
```